# java.net.http.WebSocket sending message segments of message greater than 16k fails

Tags: java, websocket

My Java client application sends data to server over WebSocket. In some rare cases data is more than 16k. Code splits data in segments and sends one by one segment using method
`ws.sendBinary(segmentMessageData, false).join();`.
When sending last segment, second argument is true. First 16k segment is sent. When second (last) segment is sent, I get error:

```
SEVERE: WebSocketClientPeer#onClose statusCode [1009], reason [No async message support and buffer too small. Buffer size: [16,384], Message size: [1,656]]
```

As you see, buffer is fairly bigger then data.
WebSocket is opened using builder

```
import java.net.http.WebSocket;

// ...

WebSocket.Builder wsBuilder = HttpClient.newHttpClient().newWebSocketBuilder();
ws = wsBuilder.buildAsync(URI.create("wss://myserver.dummy.com/wsweb"), this).join();
```

Client code uses Java 11 websocket. Server side uses Tomcat WebSocket. Server nicely sends data larger then 16k and java client gets them (and combines into single pacakge).
This is legacy application where server resides in cloud and WebSocket is used. There is implementation which uses Windows C++ native client and it works fine. We want platform independent client.
How to send more then 16k of data using Java 11 WebSocket?
Please note: Sending works fine if data is less then 16k and no fragmentation.

Figured out strange thing:
If sum of two segments i smaller or equal to 16k, send works. If sum exceeds 16k by only one byte, second send fails.
It looks like some internal buffer is not rewind and second send tries to append data to same buffer.

Please note. This is not Spring Boot. This is Java11 java.net.http.WebSocket class.
[Official documentation of send method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/WebSocket.html#sendBinary(java.nio.ByteBuffer,boolean))

Edit:
Created simple test to send dummy data

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.WebSocket;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

WebSocket.Builder wsBuilder = HttpClient.newHttpClient().newWebSocketBuilder();
WebSocket ws = wsBuilder.buildAsync(URI.create("ws://127.0.0.1/wsendpoint"), this).join();
// Wait for handshake to complete, then send data
ByteBuffer bbuf1 = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[15 * 1024]);
ByteBuffer bbuf2 = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[1024]);
ws.sendBinary(bbuf1, false).join();
ws.sendBinary(bbuf2, true).join();
```

This works if second buffer is 1024. When I increase second buffer by 1, send fails.
I concluded that sending would fail if sum of sizes of two messages is more than 16k.
Fragmentation is must since server combines fragments and processes whole message.

Edit2: According to IETF, WebSocket must support fragmentation. Here is official documentation [Data Framing - Fragmentation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-5.4)
Relevant part of the document:
The primary purpose of fragmentation is to allow sending a message
that is of unknown size when the message is started without having to
buffer that message.  If messages couldn't be fragmented, then an
endpoint would have to buffer the entire message so its length could
be counted before the first byte is sent.  With fragmentation, a
server or intermediary may choose a reasonable size buffer and, when
the buffer is full, write a fragment to the network.

Java 11 is doing exactly oposite. It is buffering segments till flag last of method sendBinary is true, then sends whole buffer. Pay attention to error mesage:

```
buffer too small. Buffer size: [16,384], Message size: [1,656]
```

Comment: What is `wsBuilder`? Where is the client code that reads from the web socket?

Comment: @aled  I added definition of wsBuilder. Reading works fine. Problem is in sending.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increase output buffer for spring sockjs websocket server implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21730566/how-to-increase-output-buffer-for-spring-sockjs-websocket-server-implementation) - That said, if you're sending _that_ much data, consider paginating/chunking the data itself and have the receiver do the aggregation. Those are some *huge* messages you're sending, sending that in smaller, numerated chunks would be an excellent idea.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans This is not Spring application. Code uses Java 11 java.net.http.WebSocket. It is legacy application which is hosted on web and WebSocket support was added. It is out of the question to change protocol. In house C++ implemented Windows native library works. We want to add Mac client support.

Comment: Why is the boolean parameter to `sendBinary()` set to false?

Comment: @aled when sending first part it is false, when sending last part, it is true. Please check official documentation.
`last - true if this invocation completes the message, false otherwise`

Comment: Then why you are not showing the full code related to the sending? You are not providing the details related to your question. You should provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java WebSocket message limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61577378/java-websocket-message-limit)

Comment: @zdenko.s not sure what you think I'm telling you to do, but keep using websockets, just organize your data in paged sets, bump up the API version for that so your old clients don't break since they already don't work for the usecase you now have (you _are_ using versioning, hopefully) and update your client to accumulate data until they have the full dataset. But also, as aled pointed out: please show [mcve] code (and of course, _test_ that MCVE before putting it in your post, because running through the MCVE exercise is primarily for _your_ benefit, as a debugging process)

Comment: @aled  'Java WebSocket message limit' sends one big message and last parameter is true. I split message in segments. When sending segments I specify last=false for every segment except last segment, then I specify last=true.

Comment: @zdenko.s have actually tried the solution? The error seems to suggest that the buffer size applies to the entire message, not to each partial segment.

Comment: This does not seem to be a problem with Java's `WebSocket` implementation. You're getting a "message too big" error **from the server**. Your server is apparently configured to accept messages of up to 16,384 bytes (16 KiB) in length. Any larger and the server closes the connection with a `1009` status code. Note a message is all data sent _until_ you pass `true` for `last`. You may have two calls to `sendBinary` in your example, but those two calls make up _a single message_.

Comment: What I believe @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans is suggesting you to do is split up your message into multiple distinct messages. You may think you're already doing that, but you're not (as explained previously). The server would then need to (re)combine these distinct messages as appropriate.

Comment: @Slaw WebSocket is supposed to send fragment with flag MORE=true. It is exactly what Tomcat implementation is doing. When sending last segment more is false. Purpose of parameter last, in methos sendBinary is splitting messages. WebSocket should send out message and set correct buffer. Other side would check flag MORE. Please read my update to question

Comment: Inspecting the network traffic with Wireshark between Java's `WebSocket` (on Java 11) and a tiny local web socket server (implemented with ktor 2.3.4), Java's `WebSocket` is sending the message fragmented as expected. The first `sendBinary` call sends a binary packet with `fin` set to "false", then the second `sendBinary` call sends a continuation packet with `fin` set to "true".

Comment: @Slaw Can you post your code?

Comment: @Slaw please try to send two packages which sum of size is more then 16k. My Java 11 test app works if sum of sizes of packages is 16k or less.

Comment: Looking into this a little more, there seems to be two limits involved here: Max **frame** size and max **message** size. Kotlin's Ktor library has a somewhat confusingly named `maxFrameSize` property. When using `webSocket`, which apparently collects fragmented messages into a single frame for ease of processing, that property is functionally the max frame size _and_ the max _message_ size. However, when using `webSocketRaw`, you get each individual frame. Now that property is only the max frame size, and the message may be larger. But it's more work for the developer to combine the fragments

Comment: Python's FastAPI library (with WebSockets) appears to do something similar (i.e., it collects fragmented messages into a single "frame" for ease of processing). But its max size is controlled by `--ws-max-size` argument, at least when using Uvicorn. That is the max _message_ size. Couldn't figure out how to set the max _frame_ size there, nor how to access each frame individually.

Comment: Anyway, my point is I believe you're running into a **message** size limit (_imposed by the server_), not a **frame** size limit. Fragmentation only helps with the latter, not the former. And note a single message consists of one _or more_ frames. Your code is sending two frames, but only one message.

Comment: @Slaw I was thinking about same. the server side problem. First. WebSocket on server side combines fragments and ONLY when whole message is recived, delivers to server. WebSocket layer implementation is doing it.
I made test using Java 8 javax.websocket package and tyrus implementation. javax websocket method implementation will split internally. sendBinary method accepts only one parameter ByteBuffer. Implementation will do fragmentation. In my server case, server closes connection when dummy data is received. In case of Java 11, exception was thrown by client. Did you make test I assked?

Comment: This is the code I was using: https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/3602052. It's in Kotlin, because Ktor is a Kotlin library, but it's still using the Java `java.net.http.WebClient` API for the client. You can inspect the network traffic over the loopback interface with Wireshark yourself if you feel you need to. I will probably delete the snippet some time in the next few days.

Comment: "_In case of Java 11, exception was thrown by client_" – Assuming my code is representative of your problem, that is not exactly what happened. Your client may have thrown an exception, but only in response to an error code returned by the server. The server closes the connection with a `1009` "Message Too Big" error. Your client reports that as a "severe" event in the logs. That does not mean that `WebSocket` is not sending multiple frames. It is. But your server is imposing a total message size limit and closes the connection when that limit is broken.

Comment: @Slaw Problem fixed. I will explain in answer

Answer (score 0):

Application was creating data larger then 16k. Custom protocol was developed to split messages into chunks max size 16k. Each chunk is sent by Java WebSocket send method and parameter **last** was set to true. This way, Java WS did not try to combine data and sent one "app specific segment" as soon as send method was invoked. I could split "app specific segment" to smaller parts and send them one by one and specify last=false and when I filled 16k buffer specify last=true.
Java WS does not support sending messages when sum of message size till last=true, is bigger then 16k.

Comment: "_Java WS does not support sending messages when sum of message size till last=true, is bigger then 16k._" -- You keep saying this, but it's simply not true. The code I linked in another [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77144394/java-net-http-websocket-sending-message-segments-of-message-greater-than-16k-fai/77175874#comment136027430_77144394) even shows a fragmented 17KiB message being sent _successfully_. Your problem has nothing to do with the `java.net.http.WebSocket` client and everything to do with the server imposing a total message size limit.

Comment: @Slaw Server is behind AWS API gateway. If you managed to send 17k messages, in that case AWS API gateway closes connection. My Web Socket server does not get any message (it was reason I concluded that messages does not leave client). We have C++ implementation which works fine. It works for many years. I added "pure Java" implementation. C++ WebSocket implementation may work because our internal protocol splits messages to chunks of 16k. C++ code makes web socket segment of max 16k. It works well with AWS API gateway. I will turn on logging on AWS API gateway to see messages.